# Returning object after deserializing if property exists c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have a Person class and Interest class. Person class has a property that contains a list of the Interest class. Currently, I am deserializing the json and then I am looping through each of the Person object to see if it contains a list of interests. This approach is taking a very long time to complete. Is there a more efficient way of doing this instead of looping through all of Person object?

Comment: How many `Person` objects are we talking about, and how long is "a very long time"?

Comment: "How can I improve this code you've never seen?" Your description is so vague I couldn't write my own code to do whatever it is you're doing, much less identify where yours could be improved. Your code might be slow because you mistakenly did something wrong. The problem could be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var returnedPersons = Deserialize(Result); //replace with whatever you deserialize to.

returnedPersons.Where(x => x.Interests.Count > 0).ToList(); //here you use linq to grab whatever you want
```

Again, not sure how big of a return you have of `persons` and how long is `a very long time`. But this would be the industry standard to getting a list of all the `persons` that have a list of `interests`

Comment: This makes sense, I am looping through about 7000 person objects and it is taking about 30 minutes. I will try this and thanks!

Comment: Np! Remember to upvote and mark as answered if it works for you :)

Comment: @RonT Offhand, that sounds like it should take a fraction of a second. I know you're not able to paste code into the question box, but if you were able to show us your actual code, we could probably help you.